# jQuery code in Vue.js components in official Laravel Passport Package

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, laravel, vue.js, vue-component

I have downloaded official Passport package of Laravel which comes with Vue.js Components for creating managing OAuth clients.
I am new to Laravel and Vue.js so I started reading its code wondering how do they write Vue components.
I found below code in **Clients.vue**:

```
         /**
         * Show the form for creating new clients.
         */

        showCreateClientForm() {
            $('#modal-create-client').modal('show');
        },

        prepareComponent() {
            this.getClients();

            $('#modal-create-client').on('shown.bs.modal', () => {
                $('#create-client-name').focus();
            });

            $('#modal-edit-client').on('shown.bs.modal', () => {
                $('#edit-client-name').focus();
            });
        },
```

Since this is a large component so I am only pasting these two methods here.
1- Is it okay to write jQuery code in Vue.js? Vue.js plays with Virtual DOM, whereas jQuery works with actual DOM.
2- I have an HTML template which is fully made in bootstrap and jQuery, i am planning to use Vue.js, will I be writing code like above? Mixture of Vue.js and jQuery?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. There's nothing wrong with jQuery in a `Vue.js` component.
2. Sure, that's fine.

Note that your question is about `best practices` which are off-topic. This is because they are ever changing, especially at the behest of the developer(s) on the project.

Utilize what you feel comfortable with. Get it working. Ship it.

If you feel the need to change it later when you're more familiar, that's OK too.